# How would I reverse this equation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, math, ios

I’m using this equation to convert steps to estimated calories lost.

I now need to do the opposite and convert total calories to estimated steps.

This is the equation I’m using for steps to calories:

```
+(CGFloat) totalCalories:(NSUInteger)TotalStepsTaken weight:(CGFloat)PersonsWeight{
    CGFloat TotalMinutesElapsed = (float)TotalStepsTaken / AverageStepsPerMinute; //Average Steps Per Minute is Equal to 100

    CGFloat EstimatedCaloriesBurned = PersonsWeight * TotalMinutesElapsed * Walking3MphRate; //Walking3MphRate = 0.040; 

    return EstimatedCaloriesBurned;
}
```

It’s written in Objective-C, but I tried to make it as readable as possible.

All calculations are being done over a 1 hour period.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Thank Roger, forgot I could do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the algebra, I don't know Obj-C syntax...

```
Steps = round( Calories * StepsPerMinute / (Weight * WalkRate) );
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! I really need to brush up on my math skills.